# SNMPget and bash gives strange results (gauge32 values incorrect)

Tags: bash, redhat, snmp

Reallly strange to me but here is the problem.

If I use an SNMP client such as ManageEngineMibBrowser to query the appliance I get what look like reasonable Numbers:

```
dpStatusMemoryStatusUsage.0 97
dpStatusMemoryStatusTotalMemory.0 33015552
dpStatusMemoryStatusUsedMemory.0 31928048
dpStatusMemoryStatusFreeMemory.0 1087504
dpStatusMemoryStatusReqMemory.0 4294967295
dpStatusMemoryStatusXG4Usage.0 4294967295
dpStatusMemoryStatusHoldMemory.0 4294967295
```

How do I justify Reasonable? Well simple maths shows that if TotalMemory is 3301552 and UsedMemory is 31928048 Then a percentage of 97% for Usage seems right (plus I double checked with the GUI :)

Now then I run the same commands on the same using snmpget on Linux and get the following (they are OIDS but in the same order as above):

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.1.0 = Gauge32: 36
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.2.0 = Gauge32: 99197400
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.3.0 = Gauge32: 36004164
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.4.0 = Gauge32: 63193236
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.5.0 = Gauge32: 4294967295
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.6.0 = Gauge32: 4294967295
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.14685.3.1.5.7.0 = Gauge32: 4294967295
```

As you can see they are all of the type Gauge32.... but the first 4 values are totally different! Do I need to do some kind of conversion? If so, Why are the first 4 different and the last 3 not when they are all of the same type? Am I being really dumb? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can notice that the same values 4,294,967,295 represents the max value of gauge32 which is (2^32) - 1. This is probably why it has not been changed between the two readings.

To check the different values, you need to compare them with actual readings (taken at the same time) to figure out what type of conversion is done. This is the best I can tell for now :)